# Error while testing android device using appium and selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, eclipse, maven

I get this error and cannot start the device:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. 
Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
Original error: Error executing adbExec. 
Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-8512546_latest\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s AA5DY9JBON69SGUC shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy'' exited with code 255'; 
Command output: 
Exception occurred while executing 'delete':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.enforceWritePermission(SettingsProvider.java:2374)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1413)
    at 

Exception occurred while executing 'delete':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
    at 
com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.onCommand(SettingsService.java:281)
    at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService.onShellCommand(SettingsService.java:49)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:936)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:820)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1166)

java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 17 more
```

I'm using these dependencies

```
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.141.59</version>


<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>7.0.0</version>
```

and connected the device correctly. Here's my code:

public class CalculatorTest {

```
static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;


public static void main(String[] args) {

            openCalculator();
}   
public static void openCalculator() throws MalformedURLException  {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "realme C15");
    cap.setCapability("udid", "AA5DY9JBON69SGUC");
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "11");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.coloros.calculator");
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
    
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url , cap);        
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Remove the selenium dependency and try running, it should work

Comment: +1 you only need the java-client for Appium.  Unless you fancy a trip to jar hell ?